# How to exclude a subdomain from a wildcard record

Tags: amazon-web-services, dns, subdomain

I am trying to set up wildcard domains for my application however if I set it up using the following CNAME record  `*.example.com CNAME example.com` it would override an existing record  `blog.example.com CNAME example.helpsite.com` that I use for my blog.

How can I set up my wildcard record so it excludes the record for my blog? I am fairly new to the DNS world so any guidance would be much appreciated.

Comment: 1) do not wildcard a domain to itself using a CNAME. 2) You cannot have a CNAME at the same level as other resource records. `*` is the same level as `blog`. 3) Why do you want/need a wildcard? Specify the domains/subdomains/zones you support. There are many reasons not to support wildcards: spam, hackers, decreased search rankings, ...

Comment: I need a wildcard record to assign a subdomain to each registered user since it's not possible to know which subdomain will be used in advance. All subdomain request are handled at the application level only for those registered to mitigate security concerns.

Comment: Read my comments #1 and #2 again.